# 433.2Mhz receiver for Arduino

Tags: arduino, rf

First of all I'm quite new to the subject of electrical engineering (I'm a software engineer) especially to RF! so forgive me if I forgot something to add to this question. I've done the research but I'm stuck and in need of some guidance.

**My challenge:**
My end goal is to build a handheld device (Arduino + custom PCB) to convert a 433Mhz signal, process it and forward it via bluetooth to an application and process the data there. I have no control over the transmitting device. I found some components such as the HC-11/12, NRF905, MX-05V but all these chips are not able to go as low as the 433.2Mhz. The HC-11 is able to go to 433.4Mhz so it just a hair out of bandwidth for my purpose.

**My work so far:**
I've been able to detect the correct frequency (433.2Mhz) and decoded all the data with a SDR. So now that I know how the protocol works I want to build the next version of the prototype with an Arduino.

**My question:**
What component do I need to receive the 433.2Mhz frequency? Or how can I modify an existing component to get to the 433.2Mhz frequency?

I want to keep the package as simple and small as possible so the simple interface of a HC-11 is preferred taking into account the simple pinout and the ability to solder it to a custom PCB.

Comment: There’s plenty of 433MHz receivers and they’re cheap. As to your 433.2 vs the standard 433.92MHz, Well I’d try the standard receiver module and see how you fare. You might want to check out the transmitter to see if it has a frequency written on it or the SAW device that determines the frequency. You can buy commercial rf remote control to BLE/WiFi for cheap and load your own firmware onto the using the Arduino IDE. Google Tuya.

Comment: Do you know what the modulation/protocol is? Some chips may be designed to work only for specific types of signals, frequency is just one parameter among many. Once you know the specific protocol it lat be easier to find relevant chips for that.

Comment: An indication of what the sending device is may help (or not).

Comment: @jcaron The sending device is not a popular device so that will not help as there's no (public) documentation about it. I know that the modulation protocol is FSK so that's why the cheap receiver doesn't work because that uses ASK/OOK.

Comment: @Kartman The only noticeable component is a crystal on the back with the lettering: 'SDE 62.050Mhz' (back: https://ibb.co/Y3nMvd6, front: https://ibb.co/L0809BG). I tried multiple devices that support FSK but without the correct channel/frequency I'm unable to receive any data.

Comment: The issue is that radios are usually designed for specific protocols, including frequency, bandwidth, modulation, encoding, preambles, etc. That’s like in 2.4 GHz: radios will usually support either WiFi or Bluetooth or Zigbee or any of the numerous other protocols using that band, but you’ll rarely have a device which can accept anything on the band (except an SDR of course). What type of device is this? I would have expected some kind of remote but I don’t see any buttons or the like. Do you have the matching receiver?

Comment: @jcaron The device is a sports timer which broadcasts the time to a big 7-segment display board. I don't own the big board (display) myself because I'm trying to digitise this device. My knowledge about RF is too low to know how I can build a specific frequency receiver. I was hoping there's an out-of-the-box receiver that can handle this frequency.

Comment: there is also something as this 434.2 MHz (perhaps xtal can be changed ?) https://docs.rs-online.com/2685/0900766b81643be2.pdf  https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TDA5210-DS-v03_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625debb399015e286e612c3cb7

Comment: @Antonio51 That's an awesome find! Would it be possible to directly connect this to an Arduino? Would you have some software examples to go with this? What do you mean by changing the xtal?

Comment: @Antonio51 I see that I have to use a secondary chip to convert the raw signals. I'm expecting to receive a stream of bits which make up the message send by the timer.

Comment: @Leon note that this is for 434.3, not 433.2. I had found it earlier and nearly wrote about it when I realised the difference. Don’t know how easy it would be to change its frequency.

Comment: The secondary chip is for a "Keelog" protocol (secure protocol). Not needed in a simple "communication. Any simple "software" can be used. XTAL change, as noted in 4.4 section, is for the "right" receiving channel ... if you need 433.2 MHz (ƒXTAL = (ƒRF - 10.7) / r), see for details. Should be 13,203125 MHz.

Comment: https://docs.rs-online.com/2685/0900766b81643be2.pdf has a XTAL of 13.242387 MHz for 434.2 MHz.

Comment: HopeRF have some chips and modules that should do what you want methinks. I’m also thinking Silabs and maybe Microchip have some chips as well for synthesized receivers with more advanced demodulation.

Comment: @Antonio51 Isn’t the NRF905 capable of this frequency? According to the datasheet on page 25 it can be set to 433.2 (https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/nRF905_rev1_1.pdf). I’m just not sure how to set this. I looked at the Arduino lib but I’m not seeing how. (https://github.com/ZakKemble/nRF905-arduino/blob/master/examples/debug/debug.ino)

Comment: Yes, through "RF - Configuration – Register", page 19?

Comment: https://github.com/ZakKemble/nRF905-arduino/blob/master/src/nRF905_config.h  see this // Frequency
// Channel 0 is 422.4MHz for the 433MHz band, each channel increments the frequency by 100KHz, so channel 10 would be 423.4MHz